# Send dropdown data through Ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I am using a contact form from a google search. I cannot seem to figure out how to send a value from a dropdown list (select) through Ajax to a php file for a contact form.

Please check out my jsfiddle.
http://jsfiddle.net/CBSeZ/

```
<?php
if($_POST)
{
    //check if its an ajax request, exit if not
    if(!isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) AND strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) != 'xmlhttprequest') {
        die();
    } 

    $to_Email       = "email@email.com"; 
    $subject        = 'TimeKeeperPro Email'; 

    //check $_POST vars are set, exit if any missing
    if(!isset($_POST["userName"]) || !isset($_POST["userEmail"]) || !isset($_POST["userSubject"]) || !isset($_POST["userMessage"]))
    {
        die();
    }

    //Sanitize input data using PHP filter_var().
    $user_Name        = filter_var($_POST["userName"], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
    $user_Email       = filter_var($_POST["userEmail"], FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL);
    $user_Subject     = filter_var($_POST["userSubject"], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
    $user_Message     = filter_var($_POST["userMessage"], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);

    //additional php validation
    if(strlen($user_Name)<1) // If length is less than 4 it will throw an HTTP error.
    {
        header('HTTP/1.1 500 Your name is too short or empty!');
        exit();
    }
    if(!filter_var($user_Email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) //email validation
    {
        header('HTTP/1.1 500 Please enter a valid email!');
        exit();
    }

    if(strlen($user_Message)<5) //check emtpy message
    {
        header('HTTP/1.1 500 Your message is too short! Please enter something.');
        exit();
    }

    //proceed with PHP email.
     $headers = 'From: '.$user_Email.'' . "\r\n" .
    'Reply-To: '.$user_Email.'' . "\r\n" .
    'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n" .
    'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n" .
    'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

    @$sentMail = mail($to_Email, $subject, $user_Message .'  -'.$user_Name,$userSubject, $headers);

    if(!$sentMail)
    {
        header('HTTP/1.1 500 Something went wrong.. Sorry!');
        exit();
    }else{
        echo 'Dear '.$user_Name .', thank you for your email! ';
        echo 'It has arrived to our inbox. We will get back to you within 2 business days.';
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: My problem was no quotes around userSubject in the PHP, and also not actually including it in the mail(). @$sentMail = mail($to_Email, $subject, $user_Subject .''. $user_Message .' From:'.$user_Name,$headers);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't have the exact error in front of me, but PHP is probably spitting something like this out into your error log:

`Unknown constant userSubject, assuming $userSubject`

`$userSubject` is, of course, `null`.
The reason for that is your unquoted key in the `$_POST` variable - `$_POST[userSubject]`.

Change it to `$_POST["userSubject"]` and it should start working.

Comment: For some reason putting quotes around userSubject completely breaks the form. I get an Internal Server Error.. I actually cannot remember why I chose to remove the quotes but it allows the rest of the form to work..

Comment: What's the body of the Internal Server Error.... because you're manually throwing Internal Server Errors in 4 places. Could it be it's just hitting one of those?

Comment: Actually, I guess no one including myself, noticed that userSubject isn't actually anywhere in the mail() portion. This is what should work, I think... @$sentMail = mail($to_Email, $subject, $user_Subject .''. $user_Message .'  From:'.$user_Name,$headers);

Answer (score 0):

make clear please, you need to do any work... then use jQuery ajax post.

```
$( "#subject" ).change(function() {
//url
//here set post to your php page
//response
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Most probably just typo, your fiddle is not working because there are additional brackets at line 45 (see console output). And your PHP script is missing quotes:

```
$user_Subject     = filter_var($_POST[userSubject], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
```

change to

```
$user_Subject     = filter_var($_POST["userSubject"], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
```

Comment: Thanks, i had pasted it and forgot to remove that